# struts2 edit page validation?

Tags: validation, struts2

I have a table which contains the profile of the user and below that i have given a button(Edit Profile) through which the user can update his/her profile, when a user click the Edit Profile a new page will be displayed which contains all the information of the user and it is populated from the database.

The problem i am facing is that validation is not happening here in this page, say a user delete his user name and tries to update his profile it should show * User Name is required
instead of that it is throwing some error, i fill validation is not happening here because the data are coming from the database but i am not sure, can anyone help me in this.

Comment: What method of Struts2 validation are you using? The `validate()` method or XML driven validation?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post any code, I'm not sure what method of validation you are using or what you have tried. Here's an example action using the `validate()` method to handle form validation.

I originally forgot to mention that you will need to change for form so that it submits to "myAction!submit" rather than just "myAction".

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport {
    /**
     * Your profile, as loaded from the database.
     */
    private Profile profile;

    /**
     * SkipValidation is required so that the validate() method is not invoked
     * prior to the execute() method. Otherwise, all fields would be blank and
     * we would end up showing validation errors on all fields.
     */
    @SkipValidation
    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        return INPUT;
    }

    @Override
    public void validate() {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(profile.getUsername())) {
            addFieldError("profile.username", "User Name is required.");
        }

        // place any additional validations here...
        // you can and should create convenience methods for performing validations.
    }

    public String submit() throws Exception {
        // persist the changes and return an appropriate response
        // e.g., redirect somewhere
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```